# iAd not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iad

Hi All I have written this code by taking help with this below mention link

Problem is: on out put only view is visible in the simulator nothing else.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsNGDuJ6-Fs

Code is as follows in .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate>{
IBOutlet ADBannerView *aBanner;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) ADBannerView *aBanner;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL bannerIsVisible;

@end
```

code in .m file

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize aBanner,bannerIsVisible;
#pragma mark ADBannerViewDelegate

-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
if (!self.bannerIsVisible){
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{

if (self.bannerIsVisible){
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animationAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
}
```

and properly link the Ad BannerView to aBanner, in .xib file

i don't know where i am lacking please help me out Friends

Getting this log

*iAdDemo[1696:207] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0x57180e0 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content}*

Comment: Problem is that Ad is not visible only view is visible and getting this Log"   iAdDemo[1696:207] ADBannerView: Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Banner view is visible but does not have content" UserInfo=0x57180e0 {ADInternalErrorCode=5, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Banner view is visible but does not have content}"

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the delegate for the Adview.

In your viewDidLoad

```
self.abanner.delegate=self;
```

Just a hint. Handle your Adview efficiently.
In your Dealloc use this

```
abanner.delegate=nil;
[abanner release];
```

Comment: but the same problem is there

Comment: Have you implemented the iAD framework... #import <iAd/iAD.h>